# C++ Wrong answer in code chef

Tags: c++

Problem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/LEBOMBS

I have tried every single test case that come to my mind. But it still gives a wrong answer. I don't know why.
Please point out if there's any error in my code. This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t, i, total, n;
    char a[1001];
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        i = 0;
        cin >> n;
        total = n;
        cin >> a;
        while (i < n) {
            if (a[i] == '1') {
                if (i == '0')
                    total -= 2;

                else if (i == 1) {
                    if (a[i - 1] == '1')
                        total--;
                    else
                        total -= 3;
                } else if (i > 1 && i < n - 1) {
                    if (a[i - 1] == '1')
                        total--;
                    else if (a[i - 2] == '1')
                        total -= 2;
                    else
                        total -= 3;
                } else {
                    if (a[i - 1] == '1')
                        ;
                    else if (a[i - 2] == '1')
                        total--;
                    else
                        total -= 2;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (total < 0)
            total = 0;
        cout << total << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. If you see the code, there is a line that says "if(total<0)total=0;" that is for the case when the number of buildings is equal to 1 or 2, because that case gave the wrong answer for the code that I wrote, but after that it gives a wrong answer. Please help.

And is there any way about how do I think a test case that might be violating my code for future reference?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Wrong Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is really complicated, and I'm not sure why it is that way:

```
bool bombs_nearby(char *bombs, int length, int index) {
    if (length == 1)
        return bombs[0] == '1';
    if (index == 0)
        return bombs[0] == '1' || bombs[1] == '1';
    if (index == length - 1)
        return bombs[length - 1] == '1' || bombs[length - 2] == '1';
    return bombs[index - 1] == '1' || bombs[index] == '1' || bombs[index + 1] == '1';
}

int remaining_buildings(char *bombs, int length) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<length; ++i)
        if (!bombs_nearby(bombs, length, i))
            total++;
    return total;
}
```

And the test case code would just be:

```
cin >> n >> a;
cout << remaining_buildings(a, n) << "\n";
```

### Test Cases

Additionally, here's a test case that you fail:

```
1 49 0101100010101110000101111101101010011010001100111
```

The correct answer is `4`, but you only claim `2` houses will survive.

### Why does your code fail that test case?

So, I spent some time re-reading your code. And it's actually not that bad of a method. I think if there was a comment describing what you were trying to do, it would have been very clear how you were going about it.

Sadly though, all of your pain is due to a **very** small bug:

```
    while (i < n) {
        if (a[i] == '1') {
            if (i == '0')
                total -= 2;
```

Note that you test `i == '0'`. You meant to do `i == 0`. You should be testing that you are not at the zeroth index, not that `i` is the `'0'` character.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code so much easier to understand, than mine. I really need to learn how to write code like that.

Comment: Also, here's a test case that you fail: `1 49 0101100010101110000101111101101010011010001100111`

Comment: And, my code is complicated because, I intended to traverse the whole string entered by the user, then check, like if I am at the position i, then I will check i-1 and i-2 positions and then accordingly count the number of buildings left. But, Thank you..

Comment: How did you find that test case?! :O

Comment: @user3822255 So I built the program above that I felt was correct. I then tested random input strings against your code and my code, and printed an output when there was a difference. I then validated the reported difference by hand. Here's the python code I used to execute this test: https://gist.github.com/sharth/85e01c78094b8dc094b4 The creation of the string `inp` is the complicated part, but it's just forming a string that looks something like `1 5 00101`.

Comment: For code chef, they also offer other people's solutions, so I could have used one those instead of the custom one that I wrote up (to compare your code against).

Comment: Additionally, if you'd like, here are some additional test cases that produce errors: https://gist.github.com/sharth/e36a41d983b7962b734a

Comment: @user3822255: And I've added one more edit that might make you a touch happier (or annoyed. I'd probably be annoyed if that was the only issue with my code).

Comment: Hahaha.. I don't know how to react. Feel like pulling my hair. Thank you so much. Some serious respect for you sir. Thank You!